# How to use Kotlin coroutines with two for loops and channels that update each other?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, channel

I am trying to learn more about Kotlin coroutines and channels by building a web crawler, modelled by [this (gopl.io/ch8/crawl3)](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/the-go-programming/9780134190570/ebook_split_081.html)

The idea is that a set of coroutines are launched, which loop through a channel of links to visit `linksToVisit`, and push all found links to another channel, `foundLinks`.

A separate for loop then loops through `foundLinks`, checks if they have already been visited, and if not, pushes them back to `linksToVisit` for the coroutines to pick up.

My code so far seems to correctly visit all the links, but does not terminate - it hangs once all the links have been visited. What have I done wrong, and is it possible to use for loops in this way?

Here is the code:

```
fun crawl(startUrl: String) = runBlocking(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).coroutineContext) {

    val linksToVisit = Channel<String>()
    launch { linksToVisit.send(startUrl) }
    val foundLinks = Channel<List<String>>()

    repeat(20) {
        launch {
            for (channel in linksToVisit) {
                val links = findLinks(channel)
                launch { foundLinks.send(links) }
            }
        }
    }

    val visitedLinks = mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>()

    for (links in foundLinks) {
        for (link in links) {
            if (!visitedLinks.contains(link)) {
                visitedLinks[link] = true
                linksToVisit.send(link)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `findLinks(channel)` retrieves the page (using JSoup) & returns a list of found links.

Side question: is JSoup compatible with coroutines?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`close()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/close.html) on the channel once there are no more links to process. Once the channel is closed, and all remaining elements have been received, the `for` loop will finish.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried adding `close()` but can't seem to crack the right place/condition to do so - I either get an exception, or it hangs still. How do I know when there are no more links to process? Assume I would need to also close linksToVisit? (It seems more obvious if there is a single for loop & channel, but having two is confusing me, as they both feed into each other - like a catch 22!)

Answer (score 0):

With the crawler use-case, using `close()` is impossible. You need a heuristic approach: Define a timeout you are willing to wait if your channel of pages is empty.

Here is a very raw implementation template:

```kotlin
    private val lastAction = AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis())
    private val pageChannel = Channel<String>(Channel.UNLIMITED)

    fun startCrawl(root: String) {
        runBlocking<Unit> {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) { 
                pageChannel.send(root) 
            }
            var current = System.currentTimeMillis()
            do {
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    crawl()
                }
                if (pageChannel.isEmpty) delay(1000)
                current = System.currentTimeMillis()
            } while (current - lastAction.get() <= 5000)
        }
    }

    suspend fun crawl() {
        val page = pageChannel.receive()
        logger.info("Processing ${page}")
        lastAction.set(System.currentTimeMillis())
        // TODO ...
        // if you find find more pages you send them to pageChannel
    }
```

You could find many more details in [krawler](https://github.com/brianmadden/krawler), a small crawler library written in coroutine-based kotlin.